# Find solution to differential equation, that satisfies $ e^{x} y(x)=2$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

I'm looking at the differential equation: $$
y^{\prime \prime}-6 y^{\prime}-7 y=0
$$
Where I have found the solutions to be: $$
y(x)=A e^{7 x}+B e^{-x}
$$

---

Now I'm being asked:
Find the solution y(x) to the differential equation, that satisfies $
e^{x} y(x)=2$ $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Can I just solve for y(x): $y(x)=2e^{-x}$ and insert it in the differential equation and show this is a solution?

Or do I have to find the solution like this? $$
e^{x} y(x)=e^{x}\left(A e^{7 x}+B e^{-x}\right) =A e^{8 x}+B=2 $$ for all x.
Which implies $
\Rightarrow \quad A=0, \quad B=2$.

So the solution becomes:
$$\Rightarrow y(x)=2 e^{-x}$$

Comment: looks good to me ...

Comment: @Aryadeva So if I'm asked to find the solution $f(x)y(x)=2$, can I always just solve y(x): $y(x)=2f^{-1}(x)$ and check if that's a solution to the differential equation?. What if insert it in the differential equation, and it doesn't satisfy the differential equation?

Comment: The first variant should be sufficient, the formula uniquely defines $y$, the only question is if it is a solution. Looks like someone took a standard exercise and then reduced the difficulty of it, but by too much.

Comment: From $y(x)=A e^{7 x}+B e^{-x}$ you deduce that $A=0$ and $B=2$. No need for calculation.